# OCaml Syntax Error at the end of nested loops

Tags: ocaml, caml

I'm trying to create a function that calculates the odds of a team winning a tournament based on the rules [here](https://www.janestreet.com/puzzles/bracketology-101-index/). I already have a python implementation [here](https://github.com/rggs/Jane-Street-Puzzles/blob/main/bracketology_101.py), but I wanted to try and do it in OCaml, a language that is very new to me. I'm running into issues with syntax errors, and it's not clear to me why I'm getting the errors. I also know that, because I'm "translating" the code from python, it is not optimal for OCaml, so if there better "OCaml ways" of doing the things I'm trying to do, I'd like to hear that feedback as well.

```
open Format
open List

let tourney = [1;16;8;9;5;12;4;13;6;11;3;14;7;10;2;15];;

let odds x =
  function y -> if x > y then 1.0-.(x/.x+.y) else y/.(x+.y);;



let replace l pos a  = List.mapi (fun i x -> if i = pos then a else x) l;;

let rec index l a =
  match l with
  | [] -> -1
  | x::xs -> if x != a then 1 + index xs a else 0;;

    
let seed_odds L seed =
  let team_ind = index tourney seed
  and rounds = [2;4;8;16]
  and round_odds = [] ;

  for i = 1 to length rounds do
    let temp = [] in
    for j = 1 to length tourney do
      0.0 :: temp;
    done;
    temp :: round_odds;
  done;
  
  for r = 0 to (length rounds)-1 do
    let groups = (length tourney) / (nth rounds r);

    for i = 0 to groups do
      let teams = slice tourney i*(nth rounds r) (i+1)*(nth rounds r);
      for t = 0 to (length teams) do
        let odds_to_advance = ref 0.0;

        
        let teams_ =
          if t < ((length teams) / 2) then slice teams ((length teams)/2) (length teams)-1 else slice teams 0 ((length teams)/2)-1 ;

        for t_ = 0 to length teams_ do
          if nth teams t != nth teams_ t_ then
            begin
              if (nth rounds r) = 2 then
                begin
                  odds_to_advance := odds_to_advance +. odds (nth teams t) (nth teams_ t_);
                end
              else
                begin
                  odds_to_advance := odds_to_advance +. (odds (nth teams t) (nth teams_ t_)) *. (nth (nth round_odds r-1 ) (index tourney (nth teams_ t_) )) ;
                end
            end
          else ()
        done;
        if nths rounds r > 2 then
          begin
            odds_to_advance := odds_to_advance *. (nth (nth round_odds r-1 ) (index tourney (nth teams t) )) ;
          end
        else ()
        (*replace (nth round_odds r) (i * (nth rounds r) + t) odds_to_advance ;*)
      done;
    done;
  done;
```

Ok, the answers to my previous issues make sense, thank you! I've updated the code and cleaned things up:

```
open Format
open Array
open List

let tourney = [1.;16.;8.;9.;5.;12.;4.;13.;6.;11.;3.;14.;7.;10.;2.;15.];;

let odds x =
  function y -> if x > y then 1.0-.(x/.x+.y) else y/.(x+.y);;

printf "The odds are %f" (odds 2. 15.);;

let replace l pos a  = List.mapi (fun i x -> if i = pos then a else x) l;;

let rec index l a =
  match l with
  | [] -> -1
  | x::xs -> if x != a then 1 + index xs a else 0;;

let rec fold_until f acc n = function
  | [] -> (acc, [])
  | h :: t as l -> if n = 0 then (acc, l)
              else fold_until f (f acc h) (n - 1) t

let slice list i k =
  let _, list = fold_until (fun _ _ -> []) [] i list in
  let taken, _ = fold_until (fun acc h -> h :: acc) [] (k - i + 1) list in
  List.rev taken;;


let seed_odds l seed =
  let team_ind = index tourney seed
  and rounds = [2;4;8;16]
  
  and round_odds = make_matrix 4 16 0.0 in
  
  for r = 0 to (length rounds)-1 do
    let groups = (length tourney) / (nth rounds r) in

    for i = 0 to groups-1 do
      let teams = slice tourney (i*(nth rounds r)) ((i+1)*(nth rounds r)) in
      for t = 0 to (length teams)-1 do
        let odds_to_advance = ref 0.0 in

        
        let teams_ =
          if t < ((length teams) / 2) then slice teams ((length teams)/2) ((length teams)-1) else slice teams 0 (((length teams)/2)-1) in

        for t_ = 0 to (length teams_)-1 do
          if nth teams t != nth teams_ t_ then
            begin
              if (nth rounds r) = 2 then
                begin
                  let od = odds (nth teams t) (nth teams_ t_) in
                  odds_to_advance := !odds_to_advance +. od
                end
              else
                begin
                  let od = odds (nth teams t) (nth teams_ t_)
                  and prev = round_odds.(r-1).(index tourney (nth teams_ t_) ) in
                  odds_to_advance := !odds_to_advance +. od *. prev
                end
            end
          else ()
        done

        if (nth rounds r) > 2 then
          begin
            let prev = round_odds.(r-1).(index tourney (nth teams t)) in
            odds_to_advance := !odds_to_advance *. prev
          end
        else()
        
        round_odds.(r).((i*(nth rounds r))+t) <- !odds_to_advance

      done
    done
  done
  round_odds.(3).(team_ind);;
 


printf "The odds of two winning right now are %f" (seed_odds tourney 2.);;
```

The only error I get now is:

```
66 |         if (nth rounds r) > 2 then
             ^^
Error: Syntax error
```

Not sure what the issue is now, because I've checked over the let statements, made sure begin/ends were closed, etc.

Comment: You need to show the specific error message you're seeing and the location in the code that it refers to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing I see is that you have quite a few instances of `let` with no matching `in`.

At the top level of a module you can have `let name = value`. This declares a value to be exported from the module (roughly speaking).

Everywhere else (inside function definitions in particular), every `let` has to have a matching `in`. The `let` expression looks like this:

```
let v = expr1 in expr2
```

It declares a local variable `v` with the value `expr1`. The scope of this local variable is `expr2`. The `in expr2` part is not optional.

Here are the lines where you have `let` with no matching `in`:

```
let team_ind = index tourney seed

let groups = (length tourney) / (nth rounds r);

let teams = slice tourney i*(nth rounds r) (i+1)*(nth rounds r);

let odds_to_advance = ref 0.0;

let teams_ =
```

All of these are syntax errors. In general you can fix them by adding `in` and removing a semicolon if you have one.

As a side comment, in OCaml semicolons are used to separate expressions that should be evaluated sequentially. The semicolon is not a statement *terminator* (as in languages influenced by C). It's a separator, similar in many ways to an operator.

**Update**

As another side comment, once you get your code working you might want to look for ways to make it more idiomatic OCaml. For example, using `List.nth` is almost always bad practice because it takes linear time to reach the nth element of a list. OCaml is not like some other languages where what they call lists are actually arrays (randomly accessible in constant time). OCaml lists are really lists (as in Lisp and other FP languages).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jeffrey. I've left the original code up for reference, but have tweaked it to reflect the changes you suggested. I'm now having an issue on line 66, but I don't see any of the issues you mentioned above.

Comment: Just looking quickly it seems you need a semicolon between the loop and the `if`. Semicolons are separators more than terminators, but you do need them when there are two expressions to separate! :-)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Does that mean there should be semicolons following the if statements within the loop too?

Comment: I don't see if statements that follow each other. I only see an if statement that's nested inside another if statement. So I don't think there is anywhere else you need a semicolon. But the compiler is the authority on this.

Comment: So after much trial and error, the complier wanted a semicolon after the else() above the line starting with round_odds.(r), along with after the done statements. Thanks for the help Jeffrey!